# .writemen in windbg of Syntax error

Tags: debugging, windbg

From the [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2009/09/23/special-command-saving-modules-using-writemem.aspx), I try run the .writemen command,

```
0:000> lm
start             end                 module name
00000000`00ad0000 00000000`00ad2c00   bbwfjlpm   (deferred) 
0:000> .writemen c:\stringtest\aa.dll 00000000`00ad0000 (00000000`00ad2c00 -0x1)
                                                                               ^ Syntax error in '.writemen c:\stringtest\aa.dll 00000000`00ad0000 (00000000`00ad2c00 -0x1)'
0:000> .writemen c:\stringtest\aa.dll 00000000`00ad0000 00000000`00ad2c00
                                                                        ^ Syntax error in '.writemen c:\stringtest\aa.dll 00000000`00ad0000 00000000`00ad2c00'
0:000> ? 00000000`00ad2c00 - 00000000`00ad0000
Evaluate expression: 11264 = 00000000`00002c00
0:000> .writemen c:\stringtest\aa.dll 00000000`00ad0000 L 2c00
                                                             ^ Syntax error in '.writemen c:\stringtest\aa.dll 00000000`00ad0000 L 2c00'
```

why I got 'Syntax error'?

Comment: updated the blog link in the question

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, here. Make sure the base is currently 16 with `n 16`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343045/how-to-dump-string-using-windbg-poi-function
Could you please help me check the question?

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe my old eyes caught the fact that you have mistyped the command. You typed ".writeme**n**" (with the last char being an 'n'). The correct command is ".writeme**m**" (with the last char being an 'm'). Your first attempt (with the spelling fixed) works for me:

```
.writemem c:\stringtest\aa.dll 00000000`00ad0000 (00000000`00ad2c00 -0x1)
```

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry