# WinDbg .foreach by reference type and get field value

Tags: c#, windbg

How I can iterate over reference type (eg MyClass) and get value for one of fields (value type)

I use next code.

```
.foreach (address  {!DumpHeap -type MyClass -short }) {!do ${address} (what I do next?) }
```

I get dump of objects, but how to get field value for all objects?

Comment: Hi. You'll need to improve the quality of your questions to avoid downvotes. Please use proper formatting tools for code blocks, and also include some analysis on what you are trying to do. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I don't know what's too broad here. There are not too many answers and a good answer needn't be very long. Only thing that could happen is that it is a duplicate. @PhilipPittle: this is related to C#, becauses it uses SOS commands for debugging it.

Comment: @ThomasW. that makes more sense. I'll remove my earlier comment.  Thought the OP's code sample was supposed to be C#

Answer (score 12):

First, you need to find out the offsets of the individual fields by dumping a single object:

```
0:016> !do 00000000115bff60 
Name: System.Action
MethodTable: 000007fedb35ff30
EEClass: 000007fedb111f90
Size: 64(0x40) bytes
 (C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll)
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fedc267680  40000ff        8        System.Object  0 instance 00000000115bff60 _target
000007fedc266138  4000100       10 ...ection.MethodBase  0 instance 0000000000000000 _methodBase
000007fedc26a798  4000101       18        System.IntPtr  1 instance      7fedf0bf238 _methodPtr
000007fedc26a798  4000102       20        System.IntPtr  1 instance      7fedf0fa850 _methodPtrAux
000007fedc267680  400010c       28        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 _invocationList
000007fedc26a798  400010d       30        System.IntPtr  1 instance                0 _invocationCount
```

Next you can use the offset in your loop. Note that I changed `-type <ClassName>` to `-mt <MethodTable>` in order to avoid conflicts. `!do` searches by substring which might include objects that you don't expect.

Depending on the type of the field, you can then use `d* ${address}+<offset> [L<length>]` to dump value types

```
0:016> .foreach (address  {!DumpHeap -mt 000007fedb35ff30 -short }) {dp ${address}+0x20 L1}
00000000`114cfc48  00000000`114ce518
...
```

or `!do poi(${address}+<offset>)` to dump .NET objects

```
0:016> .foreach (address  {!DumpHeap -mt 000007fedb35ff30 -short }) {!do poi(${address}+0x8)}
Name: PaintDotNet.Controls.UnitsComboBoxStrip
MethodTable: 000007fed94cd120
EEClass: 000007fed91b38f8
Size: 224(0xe0) bytes
 (C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\PaintDotNet.exe)
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fedc267680  400018a        8        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 __identity
000007fedb6cd320  40008e0       10 ...ponentModel.ISite  0 instance 0000000000000000 site
000007fedb6fcc18  40008e1       18 ....EventHandlerList  0 instance 00000000114d0050 events
...
```

Comment: Excellent. If the type is a string, is it possible to print only its value?

Comment: @yonisha: I'm pretty sure that it's possible. It's likely related to or similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518579/480982 I don't have a complete sample at hand. If you can wait a day, I could probably build an example.